# How to detect if the store is using developer mode via browser?

Tags: magento2, development, debugging, production-mode, browser

I usually do some store audits even without ssh access, and I'd like to be more precise checking if the store is using developer mode just browsing through the browser console.

How could I check if the store is using the developer mode instead of production mode without server access, just using my browser?

Answer (score 1):

Using an HTTP response header you can understand a store at  `production mode or developer mode`. You can get HTTP response headers  `X-Magento-Cache-Debug`. This tag status only worked on developer mode is enabled.

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html

Comment: Hi Amit, I tested and my project running in production mode return the X-Magento-Cache-Debug